# How to write an if statement in a foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am currently writing a script where a user inputs a number into a form, and the script searches through a folder for an image matching that number and displays it for the user (with download button coming). Right now my code looks like this:

```
$photo_id = trim($_REQUEST['photo_id']);
$dir = "./wp-content/uploads/easter_pics";
$images = (scandir($dir));
foreach ($images as $value); {
  $file_ext = strpos($value, ".");
  $file_name = substr($value, 0, $file_ext);
  if ($file_name === $photo_id) {
    echo ("<img src = '../wp-content/uploads/easter_pics/" . 
    $file_name . ".jpg' />");
  }
}
```

This code works only if the user inputs the number for the last image in the directory. I think I get the basic principle of what is wrong. $images keeps getting assigned the value of the last item in the array for $dir. At least I think.

The problem is I could be wrong, and also I don't know how to fix it. I want the if statement to display the image if the user input matches any photo in the directory then break.

Comment: Why do you have to iterate over the entries of the folder? If you already know what file name you are looking for, then why don't you simply check if the file under the expected path exists and that's it?

Comment: @arkascha probably to make sure nobody puts in `../../../../../etc/passwd`, although there are better ways than scanning the entire dir.

Comment: @BartFriederichs There is `realpath()`.

Comment: @arkascha I'm new to php, so I don't know the best solution. I assumed you had to iterate over each file in the array for a matching string. What would be a better way? I see someone mentioned a realpath() function

Comment: This is not php specific, it is a general note I made: since you know what ID you are looking for you know exactly how the file you are looking for is called, right? That means you can simply check if it exists, right? You are not interested in the result of the content of the folder. So all you need is 1. `file_exists()` and to make that more secure 2. `realpath()`.

Comment: @arkashca Awesome I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` is wrong:

```
foreach ($images as $value); {
```

should be

```
foreach ($images as $value) {
```

(notice the missing semicolon)

That being said, for your particular case, `foreach` over a scanned dir might not be the best solution. Try validating the input better (e.g. use `intval` if the ID is always a number) and just see if the file exists.

Comment: Ah, darnit, I missed that. I'll try using your method as well.